# Why can you have millions of actors in an application, but just 10,000 threads is too many?

Tags: multithreading, actor

Why can you have millions of actors in an application, but just 10,000 threads is too many? How is it that creating millions of actors is practical, but more than a couple threads is not? What can threads do that actors can't (or else we would use actors all the time!)?

Comment: Actors? Which programming language are you using? And 10,000 threads is a *lot* of threads.

Comment: `@Greg Hewgill:` See [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model). Any programming language with actors built-in, or with a decent actor library or framework. And why is 10,000 threads a lot? Scheduling and context-switching?

Comment: What benefit would 10,000 threads yield? Your CPU core can't actually run 10,000 operations at once - the computer would spend more time switching threads than actually executing them, not to mention each thread would have practically no address space to work with.

Comment: Unless your wrting a web server or something 10,000 is alot. Even for computers with 4 cores thats still 2,500 each.

Comment: @Rex M, @Greg Hewgill: threads are not just a way to make your program go faster. They are also a way to structure your code, just like objects or functions or methods. In particular, threads do not necessarily complicate your code, they can also make it simpler. What would you say if a language vendor told you that he has this great OO language but then you try to use it and find out it crashes if you have more than 2000 methods and ideally, you should really only have 4 methods in a "method pool" and schedule all your code onto those 4 methods by hand?

Comment: @Jörg threads are not structural like classes. They are a way to knapsack multiple linear operations into a limited physical space - the parallel capabilities of the host system. They are directly tied to the limitations of a physical resource; nothing like the virtual organization of your code.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming Scala and JVM:

Each thread reserves some amount of memory for its stack:

```
java -v
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size
```

So creating many threads will eat up your memory.

Multiple actors on the other hand may share the same stack thus being much less hungry on memory.

Comment: Besides being extremely lightweight themselves (few bytes), this I think is key. While each thread requires a certain amount of resources, actors share the resources, which is managed by the library.

Comment: that is why i use actor

Answer (score 4):

Actors and Threads are not the same kind of object.
* A thread is an actual object on your machine - it eats a predictable amount of ressources, and has an precise overhead associated with it. Hence, if you describe 1,000,000 tasks by means of giving each of them a thread, you are explicitly asking your machine for 1,000,000 times the resources of one thread.
* An actor is more of a way of explaining to your language a task unit, so it does not have a precise image at run time. Your compiler has much more freedom in using resources as it sees fit to accomplish the task you describe.

Threads are limited in their numbers precisely because they do eat resources in a precisely defined way. They consume memory, and switching to another thread has a cost. Past a certain number of threads, you will exhaust the machine's memory, or the scheduling costs will dominate your program execution. This is the kind of limit you will reach with many threads. And for all practical purposes, on today's hardware 10,000 threads is a lot.

But actors allow you to explain what you want to do in a way that is easier to understand to your programming language. As such, it can manage ressources in a much more efficient way, so that if you describe 1,000,000 tasks with actors, the environment has a much better chance to find a way to compile and run it so that it is still manageable. With respect to threads, most of the difference stems from the fact that when actors are describing a very distinct processing they can be run on *any* thread, allowing for schemes using an arbitrarily-sized pool of threads to process requests as they arrive. You don't lock the compiler in a scheme that will kill its performance : it knows it can't spawn 1,000,000 threads so it will try to accomplish it another way, and will often succeed. Freedom in deciding the number of threads allows for much optimization, the first of which using as many threads an there are cores/CPU on the machine, which yields optimal computational speed. Such a design is also much more resilient to deadlock problems since you don't deal directly with timing and locking.

As for what threads can do and not actors, there is not much, but threads being a closer representation of what is actualling happening in your machine, you have more close control on what is actually happening. So with threads, it is *theoritically* possible to achieve more performance, though in actuality using threads to beat a good compiler armed with Actors borderlines on the impossible, because the model is so much harder to use, and because the compiler knows so many things that are about impossible for you to know.
Another thing, albeit not a theoritical limitation, that Threads make possible and that actors won't be very good at, is dealing with libraries that use Threads. Indeed, threads is the base model of many environments and you have many libraries requiring you to use them in a specific manner. Actors may not be very able at that.
I can still think of another thing threads can do and not actors : real-time (I mean hard real time as in microsecond-order deadline, nano-second order jitter and code proofs and hard guarantees). I think it's possible to do real-time using an actor model, but as far as I'm aware, there is no such implementation, so until then you strictly have to do hard real-time with threads.

So why haven't we been using actors from the very beginning ?
It's like many good things in programming : it took time and experience understanding better models and implementing them. We have much better tools and languages on average than we used to 30 years ago, and it is the same thing with Actors. It emerged more recently as a better way to do concurrency.

Answer (score 3):

You generally *can* have 10,000 threads in an application.  There are no limits I know of that can stop you.

On the other hand, since few modern desktops have 10,000 processors, this is unlikely to be a good idea.

When you say "actors" are you talking about [the actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Actor_model)?  If so, it's an apples-to-oranges comparison; a thread is an actually running path of execution, and an actor is closer to a closure.  A thread has allocated resources associated with it (at the very least, for green threads, an instruction pointer location, and more for kernel threads).  An actor can be very minimal.

Comment: You can buy a ~1000 core (864, to be precise) Java accelerator right now, and in fact, they have been on sale for several years already. 10000 is just one order of magnitude away. The current machines have 16 54-core CPUs. Machines with 32 CPU slots have existed for years. The core count of a single CPU doubles every couple of months. (100-core CPUs are on sale now.) And those CPUs aren't multithreaded. Add 4-way multithreading, double the core count and the slot count and you are looking at 13824 simultaneous threads with technology that not only exists right now, but is actually affordable.

Comment: Note that I said desktops.  A dual six-core desktop (with HT, 24 logical cores) would strain most people's budgets at the moment.  Datacenter tech is a whole different game.

Answer (score 1):

The Actor Model doesn't implicitly scale to millions of Actors. That's a detail of the implementation. For instance, from [Scala Actors : A Short Tutorial](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242):

> "When actors call thread-blocking
>   operations, such as receive (or even
>   wait), the worker thread that is
>   executing the current actor (self) is
>   blocked. This means basically that the
>   actor is represented as a blocked
>   thread. Depending on the number of
>   actors you want to use, you might want
>   to avoid this, since most JVMs cannot
>   handle more than a few thousand
>   threads on standard hardware."

So it's possible to implement Actors with the same limitation as Threads (or even worse limitations in a pathological implementation).

Likewise, Threads are an abstract concept with no concrete resource requirements. Your 10,000 Thread limit is for a specific implementation (likely kernel-level Windows threads or pthreads) versus Threads in general. In fact, there's research being done to build user-level threads that scale to millions of threads. See:

- [The Qthread library](http://www.cs.sandia.gov/qthreads/)
- [Qthreads: An API for Programming with Millions of Lightweight Threads](http://www.sandia.gov/~rcmurph/doc/qt_paper.pdf)

Message Passing and Actors are a great way to manage concurrency, but they're not the only way. Before you switch to Actors-only, read [Rich Hickey's explanation](http://clojure.org/state#actors) of why he didn't include Actors in Clojure.

[Software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory) is another alternative to manage mutable shared state.